# How to insert data properly in Joomla article with content plugin?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I have created a content plugin which adds extra field on Joomla default article editor window and everything working as expected.

But the problem is with existing/old articles created before installing the plugin.

Here what I added on template/html/com_content/article/default.php

```
$checkPlugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('content', 'customdata');

<?php if ($checkPlugin && !empty($attributes->subtitle) : ?>
    <div><?php echo $attributes->subtitle; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's working perfectly when I add new article, but with existing articles showing below error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$subtitle in .......\html\com_content\article\default.php on line 41
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `isset()` to check if the object property is actualy set, like so:

```
<?php if (!empty($attributes->subtitle) && isset($attributes->subtitle)) : ?>
    <div><?php echo $attributes->subtitle; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working. Do I still need to check whether plugin installed or not  ($checkPlugin)?

Comment: No, you don't need to. If `$attributes->subtitle` depends on the plugin and the plugin is disabled, then the `isset($attributes->subtitle)` will return false ;)